# How to use "not" and "don't"

Tags: negation, contractions

While I was talking about the difference between two people or things, I tried to shorten the contrast by using *not* and *don't* and to this moment I don't know whether what I do is grammatically correct or not?

For example:

> Some people think taking part in those classes could be useful and some others don't.
>
> I like watching movie,whereas my sister doesn't.
>
> They are good at selling but another group not.
>
> some people can afford that house.others can't.

Comment: It will be better if you edit your question and leave just the first one (with rephrasing the title to be more specific) and if you post your other question separately. It would be easier for people to answer (and more likely) and it would be easier for future users of the website who have the same question to find an answer :-).

Comment: Oh, I interpreted that as one question...and I already answered. Should I fix my answer, then? I just deleted it, the other answer is better and mine is now confusing.

Comment: @modulusshift The OP posted them as one, but they are not related. I think the most important thing is that the OP gets their answer, but in a while the answer might seem awkward because the second part isn't mentioned in the question any more. My advice - when the OP posts it as a separate question (which I hope they will) just paste the second part there as an answer and cut it out from here :-) (there was no need to delete the whole answer - it was a good one.

Answer (score 2):

Your usage of "not" and "don't" is correct, but there are other things in the sentence that are incorrect. For example:

> Some people think taking part in those classes could be useful and some others don't.

This is correct, but the more idiomatic way to say this is:

> Some people think taking part in those classes could be useful and others don't.

> I like watching movie, whereas my sister doesn't.

In this sentence, "movie" should be pluralized to "movies"

> They are good at selling but another group not.

This sentence is missing a word. The word "not" should be used with an [auxillary verb](http://grammar.about.com/od/ab/g/auxverbterm.htm). (Verbs like "be", "would", "did"...)

Here, you should add "is" before the not.

> They are good at selling but another group **is not**.

or even

> They are good at selling but another group **isn't**.